# What is the common name for directories . (dot) and .. (dot dot)?

Tags: filesystems, directory

The . (dot) and .. (dot dot) exist in every directory (and probably in every OS).

As we all know (or at least should):

- . (dot) is the current directory
- .. (dot dot) is the parent directory

**Is there a common name for these special cases?**

Comment: What do you mean “these special cases”? What's wrong with the names “current directory” and “parent directory”?

Comment: @Gilles There is nothing wrong with them and I have not stated that there is something wrong with them. This question came up when I was programming a certain utility and needed a name for an enum value that would cover "." and ".." so I thought that I'd ask the world.

Answer (score 1):

I always thought it was:
`.` → [current/working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)
`..` → parent directory

It has been a while, but don't think VMS had these.

Comment: VMS does have directories, but they have a different notation using square brackets. The parent directory is `[ - ]` and the current directory is `[]`.